# method does not exist when calling spyOn

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to use Jasmine spyOn to call an angularjs controller function. I keep getting the following error:

> submit() method does not exist.

What am I missing in order for this to work?

```
    describe('myCtrler', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myModule'));
    var scope,ctrl;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
        spyOn(scope, "submit");
      ctrl = $controller('myCtrler', {
          $scope: scope
      });
    }));
    it('controller defined', inject(function() {
        expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();
    }));
    it('controller function', function() {
        expect(submit).toBeDefined();
    });
    });
   angular.module('myModule').controller('myCtrler',function($scope){
       var vm = this;
       vm.submit = function() {
       };
     });
```

Comment: The method cannot exist on the scope before the controller puts it there. Run `spyOn(...)` after `ctrl = $controller(...)`.

Comment: To check whether or not the method is defined you don't need spyOn

Comment: Your `submit()` method is in the controller and you are trying to spy it on the `$scope`

Comment: @Ilia Aptsiauri, I realise this. I want to execute the method

Comment: @Lucian what is best way to execute the method?

Comment: `spyOn(ctrl, "submit");`, and put it after `ctrl = $controller(...)` as @NikosParaskevopoulos said.

Answer (score 1):

as per the question you missed to bind the method to the scope. so you need to make as below. Hope it helps.

```
it('controller function', function() {
            expect(ctrl.submit).toBeDefined();
        });
```

Comment: Hello, while code snippets can provide a solution, please add some context to your answer so that it is easily understandable.